# IFrame properties and events

Tags: jquery, events, iframe

Consider this situation (and please don't question its reasonability):

I want to have Google in an IFrame that takes exactly half of the width of the page and full height. Fairly simply to achieve. But I want to have only one, global (for the window), scrollbar. This is where it gets problematic...

1. **I want the page window, to expand to the IFrame's height.**
   How do I do that? I'm even struggling at this moment to get the IFrame's contents height. Of course querying IFrame for height is not the way to do it, I need to query it's contents. Tried `$("iframe#google").contents().find('html').height()`, but constantly getting `null`. Just `$("iframe#google#).contents()` aready returns an empty object.
   Assuming I've figured it out somehow (with your help hopefully), how do I detect IFrame's content's height change? Is there an event I can bind a function to, or `setTimeout` is ugly, but only solution to make it responsive.
2. **I want to know when IFrame's url changes (including hash url).**
   How do I even find out current IFrame's url? `src` property doesn't seem to change when navigating to other locations.
   Again, assuming I've figured that one out, is there an event to help me detecting this? `load` does seem to do the job if the main url (without hash part) changes. But what about if I want to detect hash url change too?

Will really appreciate your help with these.

---

**EDIT**

It is probably worth noting that neither can be done with Google as they're Cross-Domain policy doesn't allow this. If the IFrame is from the same domain, the script in the first post does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$("#frameId").height($("#frameId").contents().find("html").height());`
2. `$('#frameId').contents().find("src").text();` or

   var iframeurl = document.getElementById('frameId').getAttribute('src')